# Java возможно ли передать в args, в один параметр, строку с пробелами?

Tags: java, main

В java в args нужно передать в один параметр строку с пробелами, как это сделать ?
И вообще возможно ли это или args разбирается на параметры по split(" ") ?

Comment: Это зависит не от java, а от оболочки, в которой вы запускаете программу. Попробуйте примерно так `java com.example.SomeClass "arg1-part1 arg1-part2 arg1-part3" arg2 arg3`

Comment: Спасибо. Это действительно так банально. )) Все получилось, достаточно было кавычек, как-то сразу не догадался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что символ пробела разделяет аргументы командной строки. Чтобы строка с пробелами интерпретировалась как один аргумент, заключите его в кавычки.

Например:

```
java Echo "Drink Hot Java"
Drink Hot Java
```

---

[The Java™ Tutorials — Command-Line Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)